# Parsing a enumerator with a random to determine left or right by using a ternary operator c#

Tags: c#, enums, operator-keyword, ternary, enumerator

Hello stackoverflow community,

I'm working on a project and am stuck on the following.  What I have is a public enum HorizontalDirection class that determines Left or Right.  What I need to do is call random.Next(0, 2) with my ternary operator to determine if it is 0 move left else if 1 right.  I have not had any luck with any of the following so far.

```
Enum.Parse(random.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? HorizontalDirection.Left : HorizontalDirection.Right);

(HorizontalDirection)random.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? HorizontalDirection.Left : HorizontalDirection.Right;
```

To the majority that are more experienced than I am I apologize for taking your time on something that might seem trivial to you.  To me it's an opportunity to learn why my logic fails.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just need `(HorizontalDirection)random.Next(0, 2)`.

Comment: You also don't need to define random.Next(0, 2). random.Next(2) is enough

Comment: How can I incorporate the ladder with my ternary operator that determines if the position is left or right through 0 or 1 though?                                                                                        (HorizontalDirection)random.Next(2) == 0 ? HorizontalDirection.Left: HorizontalDirection.Right;

Comment: `What I have is a public enum HorizontalDirection class that determines Left or Right.` Please show us that enum.

Answer (score 1):

**You just need to do a random and cast it to enum:** 
This is because an int can be casted to an enum (as far as the int o is 0 or 1 !). `(myEnum)0` will return the first value of `myEnum` and so on. Good luck on your project !

```
Random rd = new Random();
HorizontalDirection direction = (HorizontalDirection) rd.Next(2);
```

And this is how it would look like with ternary operators:

```
Random rd = new Random();
var random = rd.Next(2);
HorizontalDirection direction = random == 0 ? HorizontalDirection.Left : TransactionState.Right;
```

Comment: *You just need to do a random and cast it to enum* only works if the enum values are 0 and 1.

Comment: @tymtam Edited. Thank you

Comment: @AdrianEfford and tymtam, Thank you both, this opened up a different way of looking at my problem and solving it.

Answer (score 1):

Your second option works. Here's a working example.

```
var l = new List<HorizontalDirection>();

Random r = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000;i++)
{
    var d = r.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? HorizontalDirection.Left : HorizontalDirection.Right;
    l.Add(d);
}


Console.WriteLine($"lefts: {l.Count(d => d == HorizontalDirection.Left)}, rights: {l.Count(d => d == HorizontalDirection.Right)}");
```

Output

```
lefts: 468, rights: 532
```

Comment: Thank you, between you and Adrian I achieved what I needed the code to do and learned something along the way.